# Jasmine expect toEqual but ignore additional properties on the actual object to prevent 'Expected ... not to have properties ...'

Tags: javascript, jasmine

Sometimes I need to assert only specific properties of the actual object and I don't care about the other properties.

For example:

```
const actual = [
  { a: 1, additionalProp: 'not interestig' },
  { a: 2, additionalProp: 'not interestig' }
];

expect(actual).toEqual([
  { a: 1 },
  { a: 2 }
])
```

This currently fails with:

> Expected $[0] not to have properties
>   additionalProp: 'random value'

**How can I write the expectation?**

I currently do something like this:

```
expect(actual.map(i => ({a: 1}))).toEqual([
  { a: 1 },
  { a: 2 }
])
```

but I don't like it much and it does not work for more complex objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could explicitly address specific objects and their relevant attributes?

```
expect(actual.length).toBe(2);
expect(actual[0]['a']).toBe(1);
expect(actual[1]['a']).toBe(2);
```

Another approach is using `jasmine.obectContaining`. This may be more appropriate in case the expected objects contain several properties.

```
const expected = [
    { a: 1 },
    { a: 2 }
];
expect(actual.length).toBe(expected.length);
for (let i = 0; i < expected.length; i++) {
    expect(actual[i]).toEqual(jasmine.objectContaining(expected[i]));
}
```

Comment: jasmine.objectContaining is close enough